# jquery 2.x & 1.10.1 can't make the .css() cross-browser

Tags: jquery

I have a quick function:

```
//loop through all the options and hide "dts"
$('#userSpec > option').each(function() {
  console.log(this);
  if(this.value.indexOf("d")==0) {
    $(this).css("display", "none");
  }
});
```

It works fine in the last version of Chrome for Ubuntu, Firefox, but not Opera. On the Mac the Firefox is the only one that works. I also tried to use "display", "none", "!important", changed the .css to .style or .attr - same result. I added a class with those css parameters and used .addClass, no change. Any ideas why this is happening and how I can fix it ?

Thanks much.

Comment: Why not `$(this).hide()`?

Comment: Hi BenM, .hide does not create the effect I need. Since this is a drop-down menu .hide just hides the <options> but: 1. it creates empty spaces where the options are, and 2. I can still click on them unless I use "disabled", "disabled". I'd like it to be: "display", "none". Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you're actually getting to the inside of that if statement? try removing the if statement for testing.

Comment: Actually, `.hide() === .css('display', 'none')`. From the docs > *The matched elements will be hidden immediately, with no animation. This is roughly equivalent to calling `.css('display', 'none')`, except that the value of the display property is saved in jQuery's data cache so that display can later be restored to its initial value. If an element has a display value of `inline`, then is hidden and shown, it will once again be displayed `inline`.*

Comment: Hi Kevin B. Yes it does. It works just fine on Chrome and Firefox (for linux), but not other browsers (Safari, Opera, Chrome for Mac(tested)). Same thing with "display", "block".

Comment: BenM, let me try that (even though it looks clunkier) - unless there is a .css problem I'm unaware of - and I'll let you know if .hide()=== .css('display', 'none') works. Thanks.

Comment: The only cross-browser method is to remove the `option` from the DOM completely, and then add it back in. Certain browsers don't allow `display: none` on `option` elements, as you've already highlighted. The code is likely being executed fine. Try `$(this).remove()` to check, though.

Comment: BenM, .remove works fine. I tried it for testing, of course, the only problem is not being able to recover the entries (since the data is dynamic -PHP).

Comment: Why can't you restore them? Store the removed elements in an array, an add back as necessary...

Comment: If .remove is the only true cross-browser method (for this case) I guess I will re-factor my code. Right now PHP writes the html objects first and JS manipulates them. I was hoping that .css would work :)

Comment: Bear with me, I'm working on something that might help. Give me two minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only true cross-browser method for this is to use jQuery's `.remove()` function. You can easily store the removed `option` elements in an array for restoration later. For example, the following code should achieve something similar to what you're after:

```
var to_restore = [ ],
    selectBox = $('#userSpec');

//loop through all the options and hide "dts"
selectBox.children('option').each(function() {
    if(this.value.indexOf("d")==0) 
    {
        to_restore.push({ 'index': $(this).index() - 1, 'ele': $(this) });
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

I have put together [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mst3k/) for you. This solution is not ideal, but since certain browsers do not support `display: none` on `option` elements, I think it's the only real solution to your issue.

Comment: Thank you BenM. Let me take a look at it and go test it. I'll let you know how it goes.